# Azure Container Instances - allow outbound connection to internet

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 in Container instances in Private Virtual Network. The container does not have access to the internet. How to enable access to specific URL on the internet?

Comment: Azure Container Instances will have outbound Internet connection also when put into a VNet by default. Can you describe in more detail how you created the ACI and how you test Internet connectivity?

Comment: It looks like some corporate firewall rules do not allow connection to the outside world.. I tested id by connecting to the containers shell and trying ping/curl commands.

Comment: Check this how to configure outbound and inbound traffic to a container group to acess via internet : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-egress-ip-address

Answer (score 1):

Yes [**romanzdk**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6156353/romanzdk), You are in right direction, Seems some corporate firewall rules do not allow connection to the outside world.

> By default, Azure Firewall denies (blocks) inbound and outbound
> traffic.

You can Define a use-defined route on the ACI subnet, to divert traffic to the Azure firewall.set the next hop type to VirtualAppliance, and pass the firewall's private IP address as the next hop address.

```
az network route-table route create \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
  --name DG-Route \
  --route-table-name Firewall-rt-table \
  --address-prefix 0.0.0.0/0 \
  --next-hop-type VirtualAppliance \
  --next-hop-ip-address $FW_PRIVATE_IP
```

---

```
FW_PRIVATE_IP="$(az network firewall ip-config list \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
  --firewall-name myFirewall \
  --query "[].privateIpAddress" --output tsv)"
```

Also you can create a NAT rule on the firewall to translate and filter inbound internet traffic to the application container.

For more information how to outbound and inbound traffic to a container group by overcoming firewall refer this [***Microsoft Document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-egress-ip-address)